# Searching text file uncertainity

Tags: android, search, text

Friends I have a piece of code that reads a text file and search for the matching word but there is uncertainty while searching through the text file. Sometimes it is able to match the words and sometimes it doesn't although the word exists in the text file.

Here is the code:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String display = null;
    String search = "dadas";
    //String current = "woot";

    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while(br.readLine() != null){

            if(search.equalsIgnoreCase(br.readLine())){
                display = "found";
                break;
            }

        }

        br.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    et.setText(display);
```

Here is my text file content:

```
dadaist
dadaists
dadas
daddies
daddle
daddled
daddles
daddling
```

Can anyone figure out why is this happening? Suppose i add a word "finish" in my text file and then search it, it will always find it. But if my search word is "dadas" or "dadist" it yield null in the et.

Comment: Step through the loop with the debugger and inspect br.readLine().  What does it return when you expect a match?

Comment: @Simon yes it skipped one entry everytime in while loop due to double calling on br.readLine()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `br.readLine()` twice, which means you'll skip every other line. In your case, "dadas" was on line 3, which meant it was skipped.

Try:

```
    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null){

        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase(search)){
            display = "found";
            break;
        }
        line = br.readLine();
    }
```

Comment: But suppose our is "war", then it will display found for every entry like warehouse, warrior, etc.

Comment: @MachMitch fair enough. I changed it back to your original comparison.

Comment: thank you and i wish i could get some more help regarding my project from you but outside stackoverflow

Comment: @MachMitch StackOverflow is a great place to get help, and there a lot of other people willing to help you to. Just make sure you search before you ask, ask nicely and with complete code, and accept answers if they work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're skipping every other line by calling `br.readLine()` twice

I would do something like this instead

```
    search = search.toLowerCase();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

        if(line.toLowerCase().contains(search)){
            display = "found";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think so but is there any possible way to fix it?